# How to include modified javascript library using Bower in a Rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, bower

So I'm using angular in a rails app and using bower to manage my javascript libraries. There have been a few times that have come up where I've had to modify the functionality of certain bower packages. What I've done previously is just copy the source file pulled in by bower, make the changes, then save that in my assets directory and pull that file in directly in my application.js manifest.

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this so that all my javascripts are still pulled in via bower? I know that for gemfiles, I can fork a repo and reference that version in my gemfile, is there something similar for bower?

Are there any best practices here? Thanks a bunch.

EDIT: Also I'm using a bower.json file, something like this:

```
{
  "lib": {
    "name": "bower-rails generated lib assets",
    "dependencies": {
      "angular": "latest",
        "angular-ui-router": "latest",
        "angular-animate": "latest",
        "bootstrap-sass-official": "latest",
        "angular-deckgrid":"latest",
        ...
    }
  },
  "vendor": {
    "name": "bower-rails generated vendor assets",
    "dependencies": {
      // "three.js"    : "https://raw.github.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same for bower packages. Fork the repo, make your changes, and then create your own Bower package following [this](https://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/). Once it has been registered, you can just `bower install <your-package>` directly every time :)